# How to load only specific component/pipe from angular module rather than whole module with other components

Tags: angular, typescript, module, angular7

I'm working on a project which contains a module `A` exporting lots of stuff. In some another module `B` when I want to use only one component say `C1`, I have to inject whole module `A` into `B` under `imports:[]`. Is there any way I can import only specific component from `A` rather injecting/loading whole module `A` into `B`.

Comment: You can do lazy loading for modules. So if you want component C1 to be loaded in module A and B as well, then you can create a module for C1 and inject that in both.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer might be to divide you module into several. Maybe you could consider having a module with only your pipes?

Comment: Isn't there any alternative to this approach ?

Comment: I really don't know but I think of Angulars own modules. You got ex ReactiveFormsModule which contains 21 components. You get them all if you import the module. How many components/directive do you have in your module?

Comment: Ok, 5+ pipes, 10+ components. My modules are strictly bounded with entity. Anyways thanks for info.

Answer (score 0):

Declare that pipe/component in app(root) module or create new common module(utility module) to import.